# How to display localized dataobject field value in Pimcore?

Tags: url, uri, slug, pimcore, urlslug

I have data objects with localized fields and localized URI slug field.

Controller automatically finds data object by Slug:

```
public function detailAction(
    Request $request,
    DataObject\FooDataObject $object,
    DataObject\Data\UrlSlug $urlSlug
) {
     return [
        'FooPage' => $object,
    ];
}
```

twig template:

```
<h4>{{ FooPage.headline }}</h4>
```

How to write Twig template so the value would be rendered according to the language of current Slug used to find the dataObject?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation how to use slugs is here https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Others.html#page_URL-Slug

I do not recommend to use getLocalizedValue for object -- it is much easier to set the language to $request and to allow Pimcore to do all localization job itself:

```
    public function detailAction(
        Request $request,
        DataObject\FooDataObject $object,
        DataObject\Data\UrlSlug $urlSlug
    ) {
        // set Locale from the localized field Slug
        $slugLocale = $urlSlug->getPosition();
        if ($slugLocale) {
            $request->setLocale($slugLocale);
            // you can get the locale now $request->getLocale()
        }
        // we use param converters to the matched data object ($object)
        // $urlSlug contains the context information of the slug
        return [
            'FooPage' => $object,
        ];
    }
```

All twigs templates remain the same -- the values would be rendered according to the locale of slug